# When I play a video, the video gets pixelated and laptop freezes. Is it the video card?

Tags: graphics-card, freeze, bsod

I'm using a Sony laptop with:

- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1
- Intel Core i5-2450M
- 4GB RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce 410M

I run the laptop almost all day continuously. Recently, when I was watching a video on YouTube, it crashed with the Blue Screen of Death saying `unmountable_boot_volume`. I reset the laptop (using VAIO Recovery Center), the OS is installed again and I lost all my data. 
When I used Vuze after the reset, it froze and I turned it off by long pressing the power key. And now I use uTorrent. Now, when I play a video, at some point it gets pixelated and the computer freezes. What is the problem? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unmountable_Boot_Volume is part of a notification that Windows could not properly access the hard drive.  There are numerous reasons why the OS would start to boot and then produce this message, or why after Windows had been running you were shown a BSOD with this message.  For example, your hard drive could be failing... or the connection to the hard drive could be faulty... or you could have had an infection on the system that interfered with drive access... or the file system could have been corrupted to the point that Windows could not read from it properly... and that's just four possibilities.

Now, using the VAIO recovery center to reinstall Windows (assuming you did not just then restore backed up programs and installers that carried infections... or that you did not then proceed to download infected software again via bittorrent) would have effectively removed any potential infection.  Providing that you did not reinfect your system, if you had received that notification due to an infection, you should not have seen that issue again.

The issue appeared to have continued, however.  This would indicate that the problems you face are related to the hard drive itself.  This is not a *conclusive* indication, for the issue could be one of the hard drive controller on the motherboard as well, albeit at a lower probability.

If you wish to avoid purchasing a new hard drive blindly, I would suggest this course of action.  Download a LiveCD image of some flavor of Linux.  [I recommend Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com), as in my experience the hardware support is excellent.  Burn a DVD from the image, and boot to the disc.  Then, once it loads, don't install it on the hard drive.  Instead, surf to Youtube, and watch some videos.  Since you are booting to the OS from your optical drive and running the OS in Ram, you will not be accessing your hard drive at all... and if your issues are related to your hard drive, you should not experience them.  Cost of diagnostic?  One blank DVD.  I also recommend you download and burn the disc from a different computer.

If your issues were indeed related to the NVidia 410M (very low probability), or Ram, then they would persist even after you removed the hard drive from the equation (As booting to a LiveCD essentially does that).

In Short... is it the Video Card?  Most likely it is not the integrated video controller on the motherboard.

Comment: I still have the warranty. Do you recommend me to replace the hard drive? And I don't think that infected softwares caused the crash as I do have an anti-virus. Maybe they bypassed the anti-virus, is it?

Comment: Since it is still on warranty, although it would take longer, I would have Sony deal with diagnosing and repairing it.  As to whether or not you should just replace the hard drive, I'd do the Linux LiveCD test first.  As far as an infection is concerned, you are probably right, and as I said, reinstalling Windows would also have eliminated that.  I just mentioned infections since they can be the cause in some cases... and some people searching for this issue will be brought to your question in Google, and an infection might be their cause.

Comment: I boot using the LiveCD and I play the video file using a flash drive, right? And thanks! :)

Comment: Where does the Flash Drive fit into this?  That's the first mention of one.  You said "when I was watching a video on YouTube", so that's what you do after you boot to the LiveCD.  You retrace your steps.

Comment: Am sorry if I confused you. The second time, that is, after the reset, when I said "video" I meant video being played offline.

Comment: Then feel free to try that as well.  The point of using the LiveCD, which I feel has now escaped you, is to remove your hard drive from the diagnostic procedure, and test the rest of your hardware.  However you choose to do this, whether you want to watch Youtube videos, or an offline video, is up to you.  You simply need to boot to an OS, not use your hard drive, and do the things that caused your issues before... to see if they still cause the same issues WITHOUT a hard drive.